# java.io.EOFException: at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source) - write file line by line

Tags: java

I made a simple Server-Client application to read line by line file from Server and write line by line in a new file in the client side. The application writes corretcly the lines in the file , but when the file reaches  the end, I catch this error:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at it.sendfile.socket.FileClient1.main(FileClient1.java:19)
```

my code:

```java
public class FileServer1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 3000;
        // open server socket
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            File testFile = new File("C:\\temp\\tmpbgoutcoge");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testFile));
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                outToClient.writeUTF(line);
                outToClient.writeUTF("-----------------------------");
                outToClient.flush();
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            }
            input.close();
            outToClient.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class FileClient1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\temp\\tmpbgoutcoge1.txt", true));) {
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 3000);
            DataInputStream inFromServer = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()));

            while (true) {
                String line = inFromServer.readUTF();
                System.out.println(line);
                out.write(line);
                out.println("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have to find a While stop condition when I reach the end of file, but I've tryied with (line = inFromServer.readUTF())!= null  but it's not worked.
In the FileClient1 class, I can't close the socket and the DataInputStream. A message says:"Unreachable code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

readUTF() will never return null.  You need to send a “sentinel value” before closing—a special value that indicates the end of the stream.

Obviously you want it to be something that is very unlikely to be sent in a normal use case.  I suggest `"\uffff"` (a String with length 1), since U+FFFF is guaranteed not to be a defined character.

Comment: Thanks a lot ...It works fine and in this way I can close Datainputstream and the Socket.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
 while(inFromServer.available()>0) {  
      String line = inFromServer.readUTF();
      System.out.println(line);
      out.write(line);
      out.println("\n");
 }
```

instead of

```
        while (true) {
            String line = inFromServer.readUTF();
            System.out.println(line);
            out.write(line);
            out.println("\n");
        }
```

Comment: I've tryied that solution, but I've got another error message Server side:"Connection reset by peer: socket write error"

Comment: *Never* use InputStream.available() for that.  [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) clearly states that available() does not indicate EOF, it only indicates whether you can read without blocking.